Error type 3 Error: Activity class {com.example/com.example.MainActivity} does not exist
I have created multiple flavours and routing with react native config but I'm running into the issue of Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.myapp/.MainActivity}
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist.
The app runs and build successfully as well.
 Version of react native:

  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.1",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.3"
  },


Manifest:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:supportsRtl="true">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
build.gradle:
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"



project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
        app1prod: '.env.app1prod',
        app1staging : '.env.app1staging',
        app2prod:'.env.app2prod',
        app2staging: '.env.app2staging'
]
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '../..'
    // root = file("../../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]

    /* Autolinking */
    autolinkLibrariesWithApp()
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.myapp"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
    }
    flavorDimensions "app"
     productFlavors {
        app1prod {
            applicationIdSuffix ".app1prod"
             resValue 'string', 'app_name','app1prod'
              resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        }
        app1staging {
            applicationIdSuffix ".app1staging"
             resValue 'string', 'app_name','app1staging'
              resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        }
        app2prod {
            applicationIdSuffix ".app1prod"
             resValue 'string', 'app_name','app2prod'
              resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        }
        app2staging {
             applicationIdSuffix ".app1staging"
             resValue 'string', 'app_name','app2staging'
              resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.myapp"
        }
     }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

I have tried:
Wiping the data from the phone.
Uninstalling everything and rebuild.
adding the package name to the android manifest.
adb uninstall PACKAGE_NAME
Can you tell me what to do to fix this problem?
Build Successful
Example build
